# Windows Server 2012 Azure VM intermittent access through https

Tags: azure, https, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I have an Windows Server 2012 Azure VM configured on an Azure Virtual Network.

It is running a web site on IIS8.  Both HTTP and HTTPS are configured.

A customer of the web site is having intermittent trouble accessing the HTTPS portion of the site from their corporate network.  HTTP seems to always work fine.

They sent me a packet capture log that shows attempts to access the server public ip address and getting https [rst] packets.  There did not seem to be any successful connections in the packet capture log.  The IIS8 log does not show any attempted access during the time frame of the packet capture.

Would it be some configuration of my server that would cause it to send https [rst] packets?

If the SSL packets were altered in transit, would the server respond with an https [rst] packet?

Could the Azure Virtual Network be sending the https [rst] packets?

I think that the customer uses WebSense to protect their client computers.  Could it be sending the https [rst] packets?

Comment: if the issue is **only** with that customer, then WebSense might be complaining about your certificate or something else. Can you accesses the HTTPS from other computers, but not the client's corporate network. Also, is your client using VPN or the public HTTPS Endpoint. If you use public Endpoint Virtual Network configuration has no effect.

Comment: I'm currently trying to develop an azure application within an organisation that uses WebSense and it is causing huge problems for us.  After talking with some of the network guys it seems that the majority of our problems are traceable to the WebSense changing root certificates in transit in order to inspect SSL traffic, this then seems to lead to certificate verification failures.

Answer (score 0):

This forum goes into more detail on WebSense SSL issues that are very much in line with what we have experienced - [Security issue discovered: Are you performing SSL decryption with Websense?](https://community.websense.com/forums/t/16954.aspx)